# Multiple nested SELECTs in SQL Query

Tags: sql, select

I'm creating a query to return one number: YTD as followed:

```
SELECT  TableTemp.YTD       
FROM(   
    SELECT(( select COUNT(Items.ItemID) * 100 FROM Items WHERE Items.StatusID in (5,7,11) and year(Items.Close_Date) = 2016) / ( select COUNT(Items.ItemID)  FROM Items WHERE Items.StatusID in (5,7,11,6) and year(Items.Close_Date) = 2016)  )As YTD
) AS TableTemp                                                                                                           
GROUP BY TableTemp.YTD ;
```

This works perfect, but when I add another part to return another number YTD and thisMonth:

```
SELECT  TableTemp.YTD  ,   TableTemp.thisMonth   
FROM(   

    (select(( select COUNT(Items.ItemID) * 100 FROM Items WHERE Items.StatusID in (5,7,11) and year(Items.Close_Date) = 2016) / ( select COUNT(Items.ItemID)  FROM Items WHERE Items.StatusID in (5,7,11,6) and year(Items.Close_Date) = 2016)) As YTD,
    (select ((select COUNT(Items.ItemID) * 100 FROM Items WHERE Items.StatusID in (5,7,11) and year(Items.Close_Date) = 2016 and month(Items.Close_Date) = 11) / ( select COUNT(Items.ItemID)  FROM Items WHERE Items.StatusID in (5,7,11,6) and year(Items.Close_Date) = 2016 and month(Items.Close_Date) = 11)) As thisMonth
) AS TableTemp                                                                                                           
GROUP BY TableTemp.YTD
```

Even if I simplify this to

```
SELECT  TableTemp.YTD  ,   TableTemp.thisMonth   
FROM(   

     select COUNT(Items.ItemID) As YTD
  ,  select COUNT(Items.ItemID) As thisMonth
) AS TableTemp                                                                                                           
GROUP BY TableTemp.YTD, TableTemp.thisMonth
```

I'm getting a syntax error neer select COUNT(Items.ItemID) As thisMonth

it seems that the syntax is wrong. Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Don't use functions on columns to filter the rows. Using year(...) removes the ability to access index for that volumn (in most dbs).. what db are you using?, its important to know this

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, you are getting aggregate error. Add `thisMonth` in `Group By`

```
SELECT  TableTemp.YTD, TableTemp.thisMonth   
FROM(   
    (select(( select COUNT(Items.ItemID) * 100 FROM Items WHERE Items.StatusID in (5,7,11) and year(Items.Close_Date) = 2016) / ( select COUNT(Items.ItemID)  FROM Items WHERE Items.StatusID in (5,7,11,6) and year(Items.Close_Date) = 2016)) As YTD,
    (select ((select COUNT(Items.ItemID) * 100 FROM Items WHERE Items.StatusID in (5,7,11) and year(Items.Close_Date) = 2016 and month(Items.Close_Date) = 11) / ( select COUNT(Items.ItemID)  FROM Items WHERE Items.StatusID in (5,7,11,6) and year(Items.Close_Date) = 2016 and month(Items.Close_Date) = 11)) As thisMonth
) AS TableTemp                                                                                                           
GROUP BY TableTemp.YTD, TableTemp.thisMonth
```

Comment: Incorrect syntax near 'thisMonth'.. But I'm sure this is caused by an error somewhere up in the query.

Comment: Let's simplfy the query .. even when I do 

SELECT TableTemp.YTD  ,   TableTemp.thisMonth   
 FROM( 
  
   select COUNT(Items.ItemID) As YTD
   ,  select COUNT(Items.ItemID) As thisMonth
 ) AS TableTemp                                                                                                          
 GROUP BY TableTemp.YTD, TableTemp.thisMonth

I'm getting a syntax error neer select COUNT(Items.ItemID) As thisMonth

Answer (score 0):

I think you can simplify this using conditional aggregation:

```
select selected_item_count * 100 / all_item_count, thismonth
FROM (
  SELECT count(case when Items.StatusID in (5,7,11) then 1 end) as selected_item_count, 
         count(case when Items.StatusID in (5,7,11,6) then 1 end) as all_item_count, 
         count(case when Items.StatusID in (5,7,11,6) and month(Items.Close_Date) = 11 then 1 end) As thisMonth
  FROM items
  WHERE Items.StatusID in (5,7,11,6) 
    and year(Items.Close_Date) = 2016
) t
```

I don't see why a `group by` in the outer query is needed as the inner query will only return a single row anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. It was an issue with the parentheses. I was able to fix this.

And yes, I don't really need the group by clause.